# Calling time it twice on the same object?

Tags: python

Why does the following code work? In the "t" object `timeit` is already called. By calling `timeit`  on `lst_time` and `d_time` aren't you calling `timeit` on `timeit` (since `lst_time` and `d_time` are defined in terms of "t" and `timeit` has already been called on t on them).  Why/how is this calling `timeit` on itself logically allowed?

```
import timeit
import random

for i in range(10000,1000001,20000):
         t = timeit.Timer("random.randrange(%d) in x"%i,
            "from __main__ import random,x")
         x = list(range(i))
         lst_time = t.timeit(number=1000)
         x = {j:None for j in range(i)}
         d_time = t.timeit(number=1000)
         print("%d,%10.3f,%10.3f" % (i, lst_time, d_time))
```

Comment: Why would calling `timeit` twice with the same `Timer` be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem, I'll explain how the code works:

```
t = timeit.Timer()
```

timeit.Timer - This creates a timer, which can be used later

```
lst_time = t.timeit(number=1000)
#Task 1
d_time = t.timeit(number=1000)
#Task 2
```

Calling t.timeit then starts the timer